# Press enter key using 'Press Key' keyword

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I am using Robot Framework and am trying to simulate a carriage return/key press of the enter key within a a text field. The functionality behind this element is once a page number has been entered into thie text field and the enter key pressed the viewer will navigate to that given page.

I have tried ascii codes to no avail:

```
Press Key  css=div[id='viewer-toolbar-pagination']  \\13
Press Key  css=div[id='viewer-toolbar-pagination']  \\10
Press Key  css=div[id='viewer-toolbar-pagination']  \\176
```

I have sent other ascii codes to the same element e.g. \32 (space) and that worked fine.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: \\13 works for me.

Comment: @Pekka, thanks I must be doing something wrong. Many thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To press Enter in RobotFramework selenium the code is

```
Press Keys    locator_here    ENTER
```

And Space is

```
Press Keys    locator_here    SPACE
```

Atleast Tab works like this, I haven't tested others, but I think this will help a little bit (even tho I'm 3 years late)

Comment: Thanks, had the same problem! can confirm this works

Answer (score 0):

**To press enter**

```
Press Keys   locater_here   ENTER
Press Keys   locater_here   RETURN
```

**To press Space**

```
Press Keys   locater_here   SPACE
```

**To fetch the link**

```
Press Keys   <Link Xpath>   ENTER
```

**If not working then update your selenium library into the Robot Framework**

```
pip install robotframework-seleniumlibrary    | latest version - 6.0.0
```